# Как правильно провалидировать несколько select?

Tags: javascript, select, валидация

Всем привет, в данной задаче мне нужно провалидировать `select` по выбранным `option` в плане, если хотя бы один из `select === disabled`, то не пускать в блок `else` пока не будут заполнены все `select`. Сейчас же если хотя бы 1 `select` выбрать то выводится очевидный `value` дочернего `option`. Как можно решить данную задачу?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent")
const error = document.querySelector('.error')
const select = document.querySelectorAll('.select')


parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('button')) {
    let parentBlock = e.target.closest('.parent')
    let childBlock = parentBlock.querySelectorAll('.select')
    childBlock.forEach((opt) => {
      let option = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex];
      console.log(option.disabled)
      if (option.disabled) {
        opt.classList.add("input-error");
        error.innerHTML = 'Выберите информацию из выпадающих списков'
      } else {
        opt.classList.remove("input-error");
        error.innerHTML = ""
        console.log(opt.value)
      }
    });
  }
})

const info = document.querySelector(".info")
const child = document.querySelector(".child")
const add = document.querySelector(".add")


add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  child.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterend",
    `<div class="child">
            <select class="select">
           <option value="" disabled selected>List</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
        <select class="select">
           <option value="" disabled selected>List</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
           <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
    <span class="remove">X</span>
    </div>`
  );

  parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("remove")) {
      e.target.parentNode.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <select class="select">
      <option value="" selected disabled>List</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select">
      <option value="" selected disabled>List</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button class="button">get</button>
    <div class="error"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add">add select</button>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> если хотя бы один из select === disabled, то не пускать в блок else пока не будут заполнены все select

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.button')
const parent = document.querySelector(".parent")
const error = document.querySelector('.error')
const select = document.querySelectorAll('.select')


parent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("remove")) {
    e.target.parentNode.remove();
    return
  }
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('button')) return
  let parentBlock = e.target.closest('.parent')
  let childBlock = parentBlock.querySelectorAll('.select')
  let ok = true
  childBlock.forEach((opt) => {
    let option = opt.options[opt.selectedIndex];
    if (option.disabled) {
      opt.classList.add("input-error");
      ok = false
    } else {
      opt.classList.remove("input-error");
    }
  });
  error.innerHTML = ok ? "" : 'Выберите информацию из выпадающих списков'
})

const info = document.querySelector(".info")
const child = document.querySelector(".child")
const add = document.querySelector(".add")


add.addEventListener("click", function() {
  child.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "afterend",
    `<div class="child">
                <select class="select">
               <option value="" disabled selected>List</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <select class="select">
               <option value="" disabled selected>List</option>
               <option value="5">5</option>
               <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
        <span class="remove">X</span>
        </div>`
  );

  parent.addEventListener("click", function(e) {});
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <select class="select">
      <option value="" selected disabled>List</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="select">
      <option value="" selected disabled>List</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button class="button">get</button>
    <div class="error"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="add">add select</button>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Comment: В вашем варианте else тоже отрабатывает сразу же после первого выбранного option у select, а мне нужно чтобы else отрабатывал только после всех выбранных option у select. В данном случае помогло добавить еще одну ветку такого типа  else if([...document.querySelectorAll('.select')].every(x=>x.value)). Но всё равно спасибо.

Comment: @Andrew Koshman, ты можешь сам добавить ответ со своим, правильным вариантом.